# trying to set user.keyword in my code ,yet giving error for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

i tried to add this

```
"field": "participant-id.keyword",
```

to my document

```
{
   "event": {
      "properties": {
        "participant-id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{
              "type": "keyword",
              "field": "participant-id.keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

It gave me this error , I believe i added .keyword in wrong line

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [field : participant-id.keyword]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [field : participant-id.keyword]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"field" is not a predefined parameter in "fields" so it throws an error and can't be used there, and I don't see any necessity to use that because when you add a keyword type to a field it creates `participant-id.keyword` automatically for you and you don't need to define it by yourself.
so it should be something like this:

```
{
   "event": {
      "properties": {
        "participant-id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```